# How to get separate array values in controllers of php codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This Is My Model...

```
 function data($company,$month,$year) {
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from wage where company='" . $company . "' and month='".$month."' and year ='".$year."' ");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

This Is My Controller

```
 $data = $this->excel_model->data($company, $month, $year);
```

Data is printing array like this

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(21) { ["worker_id"]=> string(4) "1001" ["name"]=> string(2) "ij"
 [1]=> array(21) { ["worker_id"]=> string(2) "23" ["name"]=> string(10) "avinash k "}
```

I want to store only index value `worker_id` to another array variable in controller itself.
Note- I want this data in controller only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the worker_id value like this,

```
 $workerid = array();
foreach($data as $d)   
    $workerid[] = $d['worker_id']; // store in array
 var_dump($workerid);
```

Comment: It's Working but only accessing 1st worker_id. i want both of id's to another array variable. Because there are number of id's.

Comment: it getting last id..thanks for helping..but how to store resulted number of id's in one array?

Comment: please check my edited answer it stores in array only

Comment: Thanks..worked fine..It takes mine more than one hr.